# Jquery not adding new bootstrap tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

My Html

these are my files i dont know where i am doing wrong but whenever i click Add button it didnt create other list

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 </head>
<body>
    <ol>
    <li>
    </li> 
    </ol>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Project.js"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```

My JS file

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("ol").append("<li></li>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `project.js` used `jQuery synax '$'`, but your `jQuery` was included after `project.js`, try placing `jQuery` link after your `project.js`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 </head>
<body>
    <ol>
    <li>
    </li> 
    </ol>
<button id="add">Add</button>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Project.js"></script> 
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

also reference your add button with a `#` sign on `$('#add')`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("ol").append("<li></li>");
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/juw8yujq/2/

Answer (score 0):

To select an element by ID, you have to prepend symbol # to ID like `$("#add")`,  not `$("add")`

Answer (score 0):

add is an ID. change $("add") to $("#add")

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#add").click(function(){
        $("ol").append("<li></li>");
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

 </head>
<body>
    <ol>
    <li>
    </li> 
    </ol>
<button id="add">Add</button>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    
</body>
</html>
```